# how do I render an tag from a response in an api call?

Tags: reactjs, api, tags

im having trouble in rendering a tag from a response instead of rendering it displays as text not as an HTML

`ternet currency making mobile payment easy, very low transaction fees, protects your identity, and it works anywhere all the time with no central authority and banks. Bitcoin is designed to have only 21 million BTC ever created, thus making it a deflationary currency. Bitcoin uses the <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en?hashing_algorithm=SHA-256">SHA-256</a> hashing algorithm with an average transaction confirmation time of 10 minutes. Miners today are mining Bitcoin using ASIC chip dedicated to only mining Bitcoin, and the hash rate has shot up to peta hashes. Being the first successful online cryptography currency, Bitcoin has inspired other alternative currencies such as <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/litecoin">Litecoin</a>, <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/peercoin">Peercoin</a>, <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/primecoin">Primecoin</a>`

this is a snippet came from a API response

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using `html-react-parser`. Once it is installed and imported to your app, it's a simple as inserting `parse(myDataVariable)` into your jsx. Check out the documentation. It's a pretty easy setup.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser